# Is there a notification for when the user changes App Stores?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm testing an in-app purchase and have been jumping between the French, UK and Australian app stores to do so. I know it's a edge case but I'd like to be able to update the price of the purchase on the screen when the user changes stores as I have been. Is there a notification for this or do I have to poll the product's priceLocal property?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't hard code the prices anyway. Use the products local price.
If apple changed the price tiers, or exchange rates changed dramatically and apple changed a locale price, then your app would have the wrong prices in it.

Comment: I *do* use the product's local price but if the user changes stores I'd like to update the local price I have displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to register an observer on the property as on all other properties with `addObserver:forKeyPath:`.